# Different chromecast action bar icon when it is connected

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have integrated chromecast in my app.I want different action bar icons when chromecast is connected and  not connected.I have created a drawable `mr_ic_media_route_holo_light.xml` and added below code to it for chromecast icon when it is not connected.But what i need to add for different chromecast icon when it is connected?I tried creating xml-`'ic_media_route_connecting_holo_light.xml`and`mr_ic_media_route_connecting_holo_light.xml`for showing icon when chromecast is connected but it doesn't work.It shows same icon when chromecast is connected or not.I am using theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.`

mr_ic_media_route_holo_light

```
  <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:oneshot="false" >

        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cast_white_24dp"
            android:duration="500"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cast_white_24dp"
            android:duration="500"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cast_white_24dp"
            android:duration="500"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cast_white_24dp"
            android:duration="500"/>

    </animation-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include another xml in your drawable, and call it mr_ic_media_route_holo_light.xml. The default content for that is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/mr_ic_media_route_on_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_checkable="true" android:state_enabled="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/mr_ic_media_route_connecting_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/mr_ic_media_route_off_holo_light" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mr_ic_media_route_disabled_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

and update the content of that to point to what you would like. Note that the default version of this file (and the referenced drawables) can be found in your `<SDK-DIR>/extras/android/support/v7/mediarouter/res/drawable`.

Comment: But the xml which i have written in question has same name-mr_ic_media_route_holo_light ..PLease check out in question..You want me to delete that xml which i have written in question and create another xml  with root element selector and in the above format?

Comment: mr_ic_media_route_holo_light.xml should have a content similar to what I mentioned. Then you can create a mr_ic_media_route_connecting_holo_light.xml to point to what the "connecting" state should be and can update  mr_ic_media_route_on_holo_light.png, mr_ic_media_route_off_holo_light.png and mr_ic_media_route_disabled_holo_light.png to whatever you like. Basically, the first xml file holds references to all states of the icon, including when it is on/off/disabled and connecting and then you can change what each reference is pointing at.